# Web App is not being activated via UrlFetchApp.fetch() but when I type the URL path in the browser address bar, it runs perfectly

Tags: google-apps-script

For Web App i use:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(350000)) {
    try {
      var ssId = e.parameter.spreadsheetId;
      if (!ssId) return ContentService.createTextOutput("No spreadsheet ID.");
      var first_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
      var first_sheet_page = first_sheet.getSheetByName('test');
      var second_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qv-snObrAouKS3UdVYh8Dh34l_WqvF3O3eLw_57ZgSI');
      var second_sheet_page = second_sheet.getSheetByName('test');
      var r = 1;
      while (second_sheet_page.getRange(r, 3).getValue()) {
        r++;
      }
      second_sheet_page.getRange(r, 3).setValue(first_sheet_page.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
    } catch (e) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(e.message);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done");
    }
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Timeout");
  }
}
```

To activate the Web App i use:

```
function vantagem() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = '1qv-snObrAouKS3UdVYh8Dh34l_WqvF3O3eLw_57ZgSI';
  const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbztVyl14tP_Hm4rUdBpl7aiwEHZQP9A7CR67CHtnjMLZG2vCY87/exec";

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl + "?spreadsheetId=" + srcSpreadsheetId);
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

When I click to run the code, the Web App is not activated.

But when I paste the URL `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?spreadsheetId=@@@@@@@@@@@@@` directly into the browser and press ENTER, the message `Done` appears showing that the Web App is activated.

What is happening that via script does not activate but via browser runs ok?

My spreadsheet with two scripts, `Web App` and `Send to Web App`:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qv-snObrAouKS3UdVYh8Dh34l_WqvF3O3eLw_57ZgSI/edit?usp=sharing

Configs Web App:

[image]

What appears on the script execution page and `console.log(res.getContentText())` is:

```
Output register too large. Output truncation.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
  <title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>
  <style>
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OUuhs.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0e.ttf) format('truetype');
}
  </style>
  <style>
  h1, h2 {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
  from {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  }
  </style>
<style>
  html, body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #404040;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
  button,
  input[type=button],
  input[type=submit] {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  }
  a,
  a:hover,
  a:visited {
  color: #427fed;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
  h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #262626;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  }
  h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #262626;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  input[type=email],
  input[type=number],
  input[type=password],
  input[type=tel],
  input[type=text],
  input[type=url] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #404040;
  }
  input[type=email]:hover,
  input[type=number]:hover,
  input[type=password]:hover,
  input[type=tel]:hover,
  input[type=text]:hover,
  input[type=url]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  input[type=email]:focus,
  input[type=number]:focus,
  input[type=password]:focus,
  input[type=tel]:focus,
  input[type=text]:focus,
  input[type=url]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #4d90fe;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
  input[type=checkbox],
  input[type=radio] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:active,
  input[type=radio]:active {
  background: #ebebeb;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:hover {
  border-color: #c6c6c6;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  input[type=radio] {
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked,
  input[type=radio]:checked {
  background: #fff;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #666;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
  content: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/menu/checkmark.png);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -5px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  }
  .stacked-label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: .5em 0;
  }
  .hidden-label {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  }
  input[type=checkbox].form-error,
  input[type=email].form-error,
  input[type=number].form-error,
  input[type=password].form-error,
  input[type=text].form-error,
  input[type=tel].form-error,
  input[type=url].form-error {
  border: 1px solid #dd4b39;
  }
  .error-msg {
  margin: .5em 0;
  display: block;
  color: #dd4b39;
  line-height: 17px;
  }
  .help-link {
  background: #dd4b39;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  }
  .help-link:visited {
  color: #fff;
  }
  .help-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #c03523;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  .help-link:active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #ae2817;
  }
  .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  }
  .content {
  padding: 0 44px;
  }
  .main {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  /* For modern browsers */
  .clearfix:before,
  .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  }
  .clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  }
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
  .clearfix {
  zoom:1;
  }
  .google-header-bar {
  height: 71px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header .logo {
  background-image: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/logo_1x.png);
  background-size: 116px 38px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  height: 38px;
  width: 116px;
  }
  .header .logo-w {
  background-image: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_112x36dp.png);
  background-size: 112px 36px;
  margin: 21px 0 0;
  }
  .header .secondary-link {
  margin: 28px 0 0;
  float: right;
  }
  .header .secondary-link a {
  font-weight: normal;
  }
  .google-header-bar.centered {
  border: 0;
  height: 108px;
  }
  .google-header-bar.centered .header .logo {
  float: none;
  margin: 40px auto 30px;
  display: block;
  }
  .google-header-bar.centered .header .secondary-link {
  display: none
  }
  .google-footer-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .footer {
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-size: .85em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  }
  .footer ul {
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  }
  .footer ul li {
  color: #737373;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  }
  .footer a {
  color: #737373;
  }
  .lang-chooser-wrap {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  }
  .lang-chooser-wrap img {
  vertical-align: top;
  }
  .lang-chooser {
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  }
  .lang-chooser option {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  }
  .hidden {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none !important;
  }
  .banner {
  text-align: center;
  }
  .card {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 25px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  width: 304px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .card > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
  }
  .rc-button,
  .rc-button:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  color:
```

Comment: From your situation of your question, I proposed a confirmation point. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I confirmed as follows.

- From `But when I paste the URL https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?spreadsheetId=@@@@@@@@@@@@@ directly into the browser and press ENTER, the message Done appears showing that the Web App is activated.`, it is considered that your Web Apps is correctly deployed.
- From `When I click to run the code, the Web App is not activated.`, when you run the script of `Spreadsheet1()` by clicking a button assigned to the function, the script of Web Apps is not run.

From the above situation, I would like to propose the following confirmation.

1. Please confirm the setting of your Web Apps, again. From your situation, I thought that the following setting might be suitable.

   - `Execute as` is `Me`.
   - `Who has access` is `Anyone`.
   - If `Who has access` is not `Anyone`, it is required to access the Web Apps using the access token. In this case, when you access Web Apps by your browser under logging into Google, the script of Web Apps is run. On the other hand, when you run the script, the script of Web Apps is not run. Because the access token is required to be used. I'm worried about this.
2. After you confirm your setting as the above, please reflect your latest script and setting to your Web Apps again. (It's just in case.)

### Added 1:

As the additional information, when the access token is used for the client script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

But in this case, please test this script by you who is the owner of your Web Apps.

```js
function vantagem() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = '###';
  const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";

  const headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppsUrl + "?spreadsheetId=" + srcSpreadsheetId, { headers });
  console.log(res.getContentText());

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This is used for automatically detecting the scope for using Web Apps.
}
```

### Added 2:

From OP's reply of `I found the problem. Instead of Anyone, it has to be Anyone, even anonymous`, I understood that you had used the classic editor.

- For classic editor

  - `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`
- For new editor

  - `Who has access to the app: Anyone`

These are the same situation.

Comment: Hello friend, I analyzed it and it is exactly as you requested, I just added the test sheet in the question to facilitate the tests.

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying and adding sample Spreadsheet. When I tested your sample Spreadsheet by setting my deployed Web Apps URL and the destination Spreadsheet ID and your function of `vantagem()` is run, no error occurs. The value is put to the destination sheet. And I can confirm `Done` in the log. I deeply apologize that my test worked fine. So, in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. At least, I could confirm the scripts of your sample Spreadsheet worked fine.

Comment: I can do whatever it takes, would what you need be a copy of the log that appears on the scripts page or something else? Just say what I do.

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying and adding the information, from `What appears on the script execution page is:`, in this case, I think that your Web Apps is not correctly deployed. In that case, when `Who has access` is not `Anyone`, such error occurs. So, can you confirm this again?

Comment: I update ```Configs Web App:``` in my question mate

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. As the additional information, I added a modified script using the access token. Could you please confirm it? But, in this case, the owner of Web Apps can access to Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: I found the problem. Instead of ```Anyone```, it has to be ```Anyone, even anonymous``` Please edit the answer and put that detail please!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. From your reply of `I found the problem. Instead of Anyone, it has to be Anyone, even anonymous`, I understood that you had used the classic editor. In that case, `Who has access to the app:` is `Anyone, even anonymous`. In the new editor, `Who has access to the app:` is `Anyone`. These are the same situation. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#deploy-web-apps)

Comment: I apologize for not see this detail and thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I apologize too. I couldn't consider the possibility that you used the classic editor from this situation. From your question, I could study. Thank you, too.